# Passing data from widget to app and getting the data int he app

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, android-listfragment, start-activity

I'm trying to start my app when the user clicks on the widget and I want to pass a boolean data to the app so that I can know when the app is started from the widget... I think that I managed to start the app from the widget, but I'm not so sure if I'm passing the data correctly... Here is my code for the widget

Widget code:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mywidgetprovider_layout);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MessageListActivity.class);
        configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        configIntent.putExtra("startedFromWidget", true);

        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

        //Postavlja click mogucnost za digme
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_sendButton, configPendingIntent);
        //Refresh widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

I tried everything to get the passed data in my activity, but nothing... I have something about onNewIntent to use, but that won't work for me, I think because my class is not extending Activity, it's extending ListFragment...

So can anyone help me? can you tell how to do this, how to pass data from widget to app and how to retrieve that data in my app?

I'm passing the boolean data because i just want to know if the app is started from the widget or not, if there is a different way to do that please do tell.

Comment: Where do you want to get the value? In `onCreate` or `onNewIntent`?

Comment: I want the data in onCreate, but I don't know to do it

Comment: Do you mean your MessageListActivity extends ListFragment rather than Activity?